# Django - Print only errors when running all tests

Tags: python, django, testing, stdout

We're using python - Django 1.10. We have more than 1000 tests. When running all the tests we're getting tons of logs to stdout. 
It mainly hurts on deployments - we're creating a docker instance and run all our tests (with python manage.py test).
I would like to somehow print only errors when running all tests. 
Is there a way to do such thing?

Comment: Do you have a `LOGGING` section in your `settings.py` that controls the logging for your application? This normally determines the apps that you have set to log, and the level at which they log.

Comment: I do. We have one logger set to write to console and file. The question is how to make this logger write only errors when running all tests.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps create a test specific `test_settings.py` that overrides the log level with `ERROR` when the tests are run.

For example, if the main `settings.py` contains:

```
LOGGING = {
    ...
    'loggers': {
        'myapp': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could create a `test_settings.py` that overrides the log level.

```
from settings import *

LOGGING['loggers']['myapp']['level'] = 'ERROR'
```

And then specify the `test_settings` when you run your tests.

```
python manage.py test --settings test_settings
```

Comment: thanks @Will Keeling. I'm getting 'No Module names test_settings'. Am I missing something? (I added the file next to out settings.py)

Comment: @user2880391 you should supply the fully qualified package name, so `--settings app.package.test_settings`. Sorry should have been clearer in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's a good idea, though following you answer I decided to use the log level as an environment variable and set it as 'ERROR' in the script that is used to run the tests.